# Authorization button not appearing in Django Ninja API docs

Tags: django, authentication, authorization, django-ninja

I am using Django Ninja to build an API, and I am having trouble getting the authorization button to appear in the API docs. I have already added the rest_auth app to my INSTALLED_APPS and add this

```
REST_AUTH_DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASS = 'rest_auth.authentication.TokenAuthentication'
```

to my Django settings file, but the button is still not appearing.and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAHub.png) is my api docs and as you see the authorization button don't appear

I expected the authorization button to appear in the API docs, so that I could use it to authenticate with my API. However, the button is not appearing.

Comment: Please show your code, where you define your router instance.

Comment: There is no such setting as `REST_AUTH_DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASS` in Django Ninja. Where did you see that?